# Can Angels die?

Tags: bible, biblical-basis, tradition, angels

In Daniel, there is an angel who has to fight for nearly three weeks in order to deliver his message, and isn't able to overcome until Michael intervenes. If there was a battle this hard, it makes me wonder if the Angel could have lost.

Is there anything in the tradition about whether or not Angels can be killed or die of other causes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Luke 20:36

> and they can no longer die; for they are like the angels

Suggests: no

Answer (score 6):

As far as Apostolic Tradition is concerned, angels cannot die, because they are spirits.

Death = reduction of a composite being into its component parts.

Man is a composite being- body + soul. So man can die if these components are separated. Since angels are not composite beings, angels cannot die.

Comment: To add a bit to lovethefaith's answer, I would say that there is more than one kind of death. If you're talking about physical death, then lovethefaith's answer is spot-on. However, if you talk about spiritual death as separation from God, then evil angels (aka demons) are either already dead, or will be at the Judgment. I would tend to the latter option, as demons are present in this world right now, and God is, of course, omnipresent.

Comment: Do you have any citations for these points?

Answer (score 1):

Some, but not all, Angels do die.

Revelation   KJV

> 20:14  And death and hell were cast into the lake of fire. This is the second death.
>
> 21:8  But the fearful, and unbelieving, and the abominable, and murderers, and whoremongers, and sorcerers, and idolaters, and all liars, shall have their part in the lake which burneth with fire and brimstone: which is the second death.
>
> 20:10  And the devil that deceived them was cast into the lake of fire and brimstone, where the beast and the false prophet are, and shall be tormented day and night for ever and ever.

I do not find that any Angels who did not rebel ever die , but at least the second death gets the bad guys.

Answer (score 0):

I was asked this morning if angels can die. Angels are holy and live in the Kingdom of Heaven. They have the LORD'S protection. How can angels who never knew any sin, die; with the exception of Lucifer and the fallen angels? The angel in Daniel 10:13 did not die but was rescued by the archangel Michael. The LORD sent support. He backs up His angels in Battle. There is no way GOD would allow and angel to perish at the hands of the evil one. Daniel 10:13 just means there's a reason why sometimes the answers to our prayers are delayed. Do not be deceived by the enemy by wasting time contemplating nonsense this nonsense. GOD'S angels are HOLY. What can kill HOLINESS? NOTHING! Evil has no power over holiness. I once asked the LORD about angels and He said He takes them from Strength, to Strength, to Strength, to Strength. They only get stronger. That angel battled 21 days with the kings of Persia and may have won the battle but it may have just taken longer to do it and the LORD may have wanted Daniel's prayer answered sooner than that particular angel would have delivered His message so the LORD send reinforcements (Michael the Archangel) to help that angel out. The Bible does not say that the angel lost the battle. The angel said that he was withstood by the prince of Persia 21 days and that he had remained there (fighting) with the kings of Persia (Daniel 10:13). That angel was battling more than just one entity.

NOTE SCRIPTURE:

> "But the prince of the kingdom of Persia withstood me one and twenty
>   days: but, lo, Michael, one of the chief princes, came to help me; and
>   I remained there with the kings of Persia"  (Daniel 10:13, KJV).

'Kings' is plural. That was one good fight that angel put up alone to battle 21 day. NOTE also, Scripture states, 21 days, not almost 21 days as mentioned above in the comment. Note this scripture states not only did the Michael the chief of princes come to help this angel but this angel still remained there. Hence, this angel "DID NOT DIE."

> "The evil will bow before the good, And the wicked at the gates of the
>   righteous" (Proverbs 14:19).

Comment: Welcome to C.SE.  This is a good answer, but not a great one - in that it relies a great deal on personal revelation over Scripture.  While I don't deny personal revelation, it's not typical of the more academic answers we favor on this site.  I'd invite you to check out our [faq] and [how we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites).