# What's the purpose of angel's fight?

Tags: catholicism, angels

In Revelation 12:7

> Then war broke out in heaven. Michael and his angels fought against
>   the dragon, and the dragon and his angels fought back.

According to common sense or human logic there isn't point for immortal beings to fight. If both are immortal, who is ever going to win? Why need to fight if one is always stronger, lets say angels always win.

In the one NDE testimony Archangel Michael hit the demon to his chest and he kept fighting back. I believe fallen angels are as intelligent as good angels and understand no point in fighting back.

According to the Catholic teaching, what is the point to an angel's fight with demons if they are both immortal and God's angels stronger? The whole idea of spirits fighting is absurd to me. Isn't really a battle over the influence? But there was fight in heavens, not involving us...

Comment: There is a fundamental assumption in your argument which is wrong. Angels are **not immortal**, only God is immortal. 1 Timothy 6:16 **Who only hath immortality**, dwelling in the light which no man can approach unto; whom no man hath seen, nor can see: to whom be honour and power everlasting. Amen.

Comment: @CRags Perhaps in Catholic teaching angels are immortal, or at least something like. Are you certain that your statement that Grasper's assumption is wrong is in fact reflective of Catholic teaching, as requested?

Comment: I don't know about Catholic teaching concerning angels. But the scriptures are clear. That's why I am posting this as a comment, just so the OP clarify further. I definitely would not answer this as I have no idea of Catholic theology

Comment: Angels are immortal spirits; their existence had a point of origin, but will have no point of termination. Yes, I need the catholic view on this...

Comment: OK, so that clarifies the question. Protestant view (biblical view) is that the fallen angels will finally be destroyed in hell. So this shows that they are not immortal, according to Protestants. I am getting out of your way with this. Sorry if this comment is deemed impolite

Comment: Related question: [Can Angels Die?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7530/can-angels-die)

Comment: In my study of the Bible, I have arrived at the conclusion that the War in Heaven was actually a war between good and evil. With Satan tempting the Angels just as he tempted Jesus and tempts us daily. And the results are the same for the fallen Angels as it is for unrepentant man or eternal punishment in the lake of fire. whether or not that aligns with the Catholic concept I do not know. But it does align with my other perceptions of God's plan.

Comment: @Bye, Angels have full knowledge so temptation makes no sense. Satan can fool them but not tempt.

Comment: Your assertion that Angels have full knowledge does not agree with: Mark 13:32 NKJV  "But of that day and hour no one knows, not even the angels in heaven, nor the Son, but only the Father. So only the Father has full knowledge. And in order to get some Angels to rebel against God Satan had to use some sort of temptation, even if it was the promise an easier existence by not having to bow down to God.

Comment: @Bye, full knowledge of God's love, not of upcoming events. This is what they see 1 Corinthians 13:12. As I said, we can't blame Satan for everything, he is also an angel. So Angels decides on their own. Satan can only fool them, meaning provide different story but the angels will decide based on their own knowledge which is the same as Satan's.

Comment: Let's not debate in comments I would open a chat for this if I were able to, but cannot due to my blindness. anyway this will be my last comment here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article [*What is a Demon?*](http://spiritualdirection.com/2012/10/13/what-is-a-demon) by [Fr. José Antonio Fortea Cucurulla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Antonio_Fortea), a Spanish writer, and a Roman Catholic priest and exorcist of the diocese of Alcalá de Henares (Madrid), speaks of what the angelic fight, a fight between spiritual beings, was all about:

> Now war arose in heaven, Michael and his angels fighting against the
>   dragon; and the dragon and his angels fought, but they were defeated
>   and there was no longer any place for them in heaven. And the great
>   dragon was thrown down, that ancient serpent, who is called the Devil
>   and Satan, the deceiver of the whole world—he was thrown down to the
>   earth, and his angels were thrown down with him (Rv 12:7-9).
>
> How can purely spiritual beings fight among themselves? What weapons
>   do they use? **Angels are spirits, so their battles must be purely
>   intellectual. The only weapons that they can use are intellectual
>   arguments.** The angels gave reasons to the rebels for why they should
>   return to obedience to God. The rebel angels countered with their
>   reasons to support their position and spread their rebellion among the
>   faithful angels. In this epic angelic battle, some who were inclined
>   to rebel returned to obedience, while some of the faithful angels were
>   seduced by the evil arguments of the rebels.

From above we see that God had asked or commanded the angels to do something. The dragon and his angels rebelled and did not want to obey and tried to instigate others to join in the rebellion with St. Michael (From the Hebrew name מִיכָאֵל (Mikha'el) [meaning](http://www.behindthename.com/name/michael) "who is like God?". This is a rhetorical question, implying no person is like God) and the faithful angels countering  with their arguments.

Revelation tells us that [a third were not faithful](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2012%3A4&version=RSVCE) and were kicked out of heaven and became the demons, the Devil or Satan and his angels.

---

As regards winning, the good side always wins (in the end) i.e. God's side always wins and he is the one who provides the victory.

> [**Rev 12:9-11 (RSVCE)**](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2012%3A9-11&version=RSVCE) **9** And the great dragon was thrown
>   down, that ancient serpent, who is called the Devil and Satan, the
>   deceiver of the whole world—he was thrown down to the earth, and his
>   angels were thrown down with him. **10** And I heard a loud voice in
>   heaven, saying, “Now the salvation and the power and the kingdom of
>   our God and the authority of his Christ have come<sup>1</sup>, for the accuser of
>   our brethren has been thrown down, who accuses them day and night
>   before our God. **11** And they have conquered him by the blood of the
>   Lamb and by the word of their testimony, for they loved not their
>   lives even unto death.

---

<sup>1. The Jerusalem Bible Popular Edition renders this: *Victory and power and empire for ever have been won by our God*</sup>

Comment: this answers my question perfectly! Thanks!